# How to run a macro through a folder containing hundreds of text files

Tags: excel, vba, visual-studio

I have a folder with hundreds of text files that I need to parse some lines from. These lines then need to be pasted to an Excel sheet continuing down in order. This is my first attempt at VBA but I managed to pull the text I want from one file and paste it into the Excel sheet but I am stuck at being able to continuously run the macro through the entire folder and continuously add the parsed text lines to the Excel sheet. Sorry if this is rough but it is my first attempt at macro writing

I tried using `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)` to call the folder that has all my text files in. I then opened the files I wanted with:

```vb
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\", vbReadOnly)
```

I then tried a Do Loop to run the macro through each file but it didn't return any value despite completing the macro it just replaced the previously obtained results.

Here is the basic portion of my code:

```vb
Sub read()
'PURPOSE: Send All Data From Text File To A String Variable

    Dim TextFile As Integer
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim FileContent As String
    Dim MyFolder As String, MyFile As String

    'Opens a file dialog box for user to select a folder
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
       .AllowMultiSelect = False
       .Show
       MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
       Err.Clear
    End With

    'File Path of Text File
    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\", vbReadOnly)

    'Determine the next file number available for use by the FileOpen function
    TextFile = FreeFile

    'Open the text file
    Open MyFile For Input As #1

    'Store file content inside a variable
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textline
        Text = Text & textline
    Loop

    Close #1
        
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.getFolder(MyFolder)
       
    Dim fls As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
       
    For Each fls In objFolder.Files
    'find required data from txt file

        starttime = InStr(Text, "+start=")
        endtime = InStr(Text, "+end=")
        so = InStr(Text, "+so=")
        engineer = InStr(Text, "+engineer=")
        account = InStr(Text, "+account=")
        incident = InStr(Text, "+number=")
        machine = InStr(Text, "+machine=")
        down = InStr(Text, "+down=")
        nextrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        'label headers for txt data
        Range("A1").Value = "       start time   "
        Range("B1").Value = "       end time   "
        Range("C1").Value = "   SO   "
        Range("D1").Value = "       Total Time    "
        Range("E1").Value = "   Engineer       "
        Range("F1").Value = "   Account"
        Range("G1").Value = "   Incident"
        Range("H1").Value = "   Machine"
        Range("I1").Value = "   down"

        'paste obtained txt data into excel cells
        Range("A2" & i).Value = Mid(Text, starttime + 7, 16)
        Range("B2").Value = Mid(Text, endtime + 5, 16)
        Range("C2").Value = Mid(Text, so + 4, 8)
        Range("E2").Value = Mid(Text, engineer + 10, 4)
        Range("F2").Value = Mid(Text, account + 9, 6)
        Range("G2").Value = Mid(Text, incident + 8, 4)
        Range("H2").Value = Mid(Text, machine + 9, 4)
        Range("I2").Value = Mid(Text, down + 6, 9)

       'Report Out macro finished
        MsgBox "      Finished        "

        'Close Text File
         Close TextFile
          
        i = i + 1
    Next
    
End Sub
```

This gives me the results I want but I have to go through each individual file which is time consuming. I would rather have it loop though the entire folder pulling the information from each file and adding the pulled text to the Excel sheet continuing down each row. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through all the files of the folder by using the below code. Amend it according to your need.

```
'First you will need to declare an object

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object

'then set this object to the address you received in first part of your code 

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.getFolder(MyFolder) 

'Now create a new object for files in that folder and apply the for loop as below

Dim fls As Object
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
For Each fls In objFolder.Files

'----- Your Code to perform on Each file
Range("A" & i+1).value ' Change all accordingly

i = i + 1
Next
```

This should do the Job!

Edit ----------- You will have to change all the fields

```
Range("A" & i + 1).Value = Mid(Text, starttime + 7, 16)
Range("B" & i + 1).Value = Mid(Text, endtime + 5, 16)
Range("C" & i + 1).Value = Mid(Text, so + 4, 8)
Range("E" & i + 1).Value = Mid(Text, engineer + 10, 4)
Range("F" & i + 1).Value = Mid(Text, account + 9, 6)
Range("G" & i + 1).Value = Mid(Text, incident + 8, 4)
Range("H" & i + 1).Value = Mid(Text, machine + 9, 4)
Range("I" & i + 1).Value = Mid(Text, down + 6, 9)
```

Edit for file opening:

You will have to open each file in the loop:

```
 MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\" fls.Name, vbReadOnly)
```

After that extract the text the way you are doing. But this have to be done in the Loop. So that the process is repeated for every file.

Comment: thanks for the input! ill try working with this

Comment: Comment if you face any error in this.

Comment: It is looping through each file now but it is not updating the excel sheet with the new values from each file. any recommendation? I suspect its because of my shotty attempt to assign a cell range for each value

Comment: Yes you will have to loop the values that your pasting. So in short you have to declare an integer i and in the same loop assign it a value 1 if you want to paste values in your excel from 1st row and change your code as "Range("A:" & i).value" . Also don't forget to add 1 to the value of i before "Next" so that in next iteration code will paste values in next row of excel.

Comment: I have amended the code. Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: @Pie - I have edited your question and added the line that works for me. Check it!

Comment: i added your bit of code but i keep getting an error ( method 'Range' of 'object _Global' failed i then tried getting rid of the colon and added A2 instead as this is where i want the values to start it will run the code Range("A2" & i).value but it places the obtained values in cell A21 it does reiterate the code but it doesn't select the next file so basically it is running the macro over the same file instead of going to the next file and calculating those values. I edit my question to reflect my updated code

Comment: Hi Change it to Range("A" & i +1).value .. That will do the job. It will start with cell A2. @user11536789

Comment: @user11536789 ... You will have to change all the fields. I have amended the answer to reflect this.  Also you are not opening each file in the loop, you have only opened one file in the beginning of your code.

Comment: At the moment your code is opening one file and applying loop over the same variables because you are not opening any file in the loop.

Comment: awesome, the range issue is fixed so it does add the new values to A2 and beyond, i moved the  MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\" fls.Name, vbReadOnly) into the loop sequence but i get an error ( compile error, Expected: list separator or )

Comment: My Mistake, I forgot to add another & in the line it should be  "MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\" & fls.Name, vbReadOnly)"                 ........ Also in your code change the Close Textfile to Close MyFile

Comment: adding,  Text = "" after close but before next solved the issue for me, thanks for your help it was much appreciated